# UICollectionview isn't loading cells when layout is horizontal until view frame is large enough

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, ios7, uicollectionviewlayout

All of my delegate are hooked up and called for a vertical layout object. In horizontal mode, for some reason the only delegate called is `numberofcellsincollectionview` (which returns correct number) - `cellforitematindexpath` isn't called unless I increase the size of the collectionview frame. when it is large enough `cellforitematindexpath` is called. This strange behavior only happens when the collectionview layout is in horizontal mode. In vertical mode not getting this behavior. (also this strange behavior only started in iOS7 - don't know if there is a connection)

horizontal layout code

```
-(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)getFilmStripLayout
{

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    CGSize s = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.height,self.frame.size.height);

    [flowLayout setItemSize:s];
    return flowLayout;
}
```

View controller containing view

```
-(UIThumbnailGalleryView *)gallery
{
    if (_gallery == nil)
    {

       CGRect r = CGRectInset(self.filmStripRect, 0, -20); // started with inset 0,0 , increased the size and then the delegates are called. 
        _gallery = [[UIThumbnailGalleryView alloc] init2WithFrame:r]; // custom initializer testing layouts
        [_gallery setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [_gallery setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]]; // setting colors in order to see the placement
        _gallery.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
        _gallery.layer.borderWidth = 3;
        _gallery.dataSource = self;
        _gallery.delegate = self;
        [_gallery setInToggleMode:YES];
    }
    return _gallery;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed strange behaviors with horizontal layout as well, especially in storyboard in regards to how the scroll view insets are handled. It could very well be an apple bug. If the view isn't large enough to hold the cell than cellForItemAtIndexPath never gets called (this is expected behavior). Try setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on your view controller to see if this resolves the issue for you.

Comment: @AndrewTheis you saved my day! Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` did the trick for me.